# Hide/show button is not working properly

Tags: javascript

I have an edit button that on click needs to disappear i've tried the following code but the button is working only for the first tr, if I click the second line the button on the first line disapears, what's wrong with my code?

```
function Edit(clickedButton){

   var getTR = clickedButton.closest('tr');
    var getLength = getTR.childElementCount;
    var getTds = getTR.querySelectorAll("td")

    for (i in getTds){
        if(i < (getLength-1)){
        getTds[i].innerHTML = "<input  type='text' value='"+getTds[i].innerHTML+"'>";
        }       
    }

    btnEdit.style.display = 'none';
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="table" class="table .table-bordered" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>DOB</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Martial Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="user">1</td>
                <td class="firstName">Sr</td>
                <td class="lastName">Kar</td>
                <td class="dob">1-12-1990</td>
                <td class="gender">Male</td>
                <td class="status">Married</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btnEdit" onclick="Edit(this)">Edit</button>
                    <button class="btnDel" onclick="Delete(this)">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td class="user">2</td>
                <td class="firstName">kajs</td>
                <td class="lastName">kasjk</td>
                <td class="dob">29-07-1995</td>
                <td class="gender">Female</td>
                <td class="status">Single</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btnEdit" onclick="Edit(this)">Edit</button>
                    <button class="btnDel" onclick="Delete(this)">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you use jQuery? Will be much easier to write it.

Comment: Actually I can't, I am trying to learn javasript

Comment: Can you add your html ?

Comment: what is the "btnEdit" equal to?

Comment: btnEdit is the class name og the button i need to hide @KiiroSora09

Answer (score 2):

To hide the button is not the responsibility of javascript! Its the responsibility of CSS! (Because: if you become in example a new request, that the edit-button must be grayed-out instead of hide, its a request to the style of the website)

```js
function Edit($button){
  var $tr = $button.closest('tr');
  $tr.toggleClass('editing');
  $tr.find("td").wrapInner(function(){
    return $('<input />').val(this.innerHTML);
  });
  
}
$('button').click(function(button){
  Edit($(this));
});
```

```css
.editing button{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <th><button>Hideme</button></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>def</td>
    <td>456</td>
    <th><button>Hideme</button></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ghi</td>
    <td>789</td>
    <th><button>Hideme</button></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```